# Как добавить текст слева от первого tab-а

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  
      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();  
  
      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");

   $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
   $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");
   
    });

 $(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {
      
      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
   
   $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");
   
   $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
   $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
    });
```

```css
ul.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 32px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
  border-top: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
  border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 width: 10.%;
}

ul.tabs li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 0px 21px;
 height: 31px;
 line-height: 31px;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #697379;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.tab_last { border-right: 1px solid #333; }

ul.tabs li:hover {
 background-color: #ccc;
 color: #333;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
 border-bottom-color:#37454d;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
 display: block;
}

.tab_container {
 border: 1px solid #333;
 border-top: none;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 overflow: auto;
}

.tab_content {
 padding: 20px;
 display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .tabs {
  display: none;
 }
 .tab_drawer_heading {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
 }
 .d_active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">Наши рекомендации</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Расстояние от центра города</li>
  <li rel="tab3">Оценка по отзывам</li>
  <li rel="tab4">Самая низкая цена</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
  
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    
  <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab2 -->

  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
 <!-- #tab3-->

   
<!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

Есть такой tab меню.Нужно добавить туда текст <<**Сортировать**>>.

Посмотрите на полном экране чтобы увидеть эффект польностью так в маленьком режиме все 4 таба не помещаются в окошко.

> Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно добавить чтобы в итоге получилось
>   как в картиньке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `<ul class="tabs" />` добавить `<li />` без атрибута `rel` и отстилизовать)

Comment: спасибо Феррари :)

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем новую li

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><span>Сортировать:<span></li>
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">Наши рекомендации</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Расстояние от центра города</li>
  <li rel="tab3">Оценка по отзывам</li>
  <li rel="tab4">Самая низкая цена</li>
</ul>
```

И добавляем стили

```
ul.tabs li:first-child {
    cursor:auto;

}
ul.tabs li:first-child:hover {
    cursor:auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    color:  #697379;
}
```